# Sum up values of the same keys in a list inside a dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, grouping, python-itertools

I have a code that reads a CSV and produces a dictionary with a municipality as key and a list of land cover classification and its area as value:

```
with open (file) as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvreader:
        result[row[1]].append(row[0])
        result[row[1]].append(row[2])
    print(result)
```

**Result 1 - NAME_2': ['DESCRIPT', 'area']**

```
{'Cabusao': ['Crop land mixed with coconut plantation', '6446690.72729492', 'Coconut plantations', '156914.753356934', 'Cultivated Area mixed with brushland/grassland', '4356221.33416748', 'Arable land, crops mainly cereals and sugar', '11530447.4974976', 'Crop land mixed with coconut plantation', '5975853.80914307', 'Coconut plantations', '9898.44506835938', 'Coconut plantations', '1389881.81445313'], ...}
```

Adding this for-loop groups the items in the list but does not add the values (only retains one of each), and puts each result into an individual dictionary.

```
for i in result:
    d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(result[i])] * 2, fillvalue=""))
    print(d)
```

**Result 2 - {'DESCRIPT': 'area'}**

```
{'Crop land mixed with coconut plantation': '5975853.80914307', 'Coconut plantations': '1389881.81445313', 'Cultivated Area mixed with brushland/grassland': '4356221.33416748', 'Arable land, crops mainly cereals and sugar': '11530447.4974976'}
```

So how do I get a result just like Result 1 but the items in the list are grouped by key and the values summed? Crop land and coco plantation are each summed here

```
{'Cabusao': ['Crop land mixed with coconut plantation':'12,422,544.53643799', 'Coconut plantations', '1,556,695.012878423', 'Cultivated Area mixed with brushland/grassland', '4356221.33416748', 'Arable land, crops mainly cereals and sugar', '11530447.4974976'], ...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Assuming the d to be the first dictionary you posted,

```
ans = {}; new_dict = {} 
for key,sub_list in d.items(): 
    for idx in range(0, len(sub_list), 2): 
         if sub_list[idx] not in new_dict:
             new_dict[sub_list[idx]] = float(sub_list[idx+1]) 
         new_dict[sub_list[idx]] += float(sub_list[idx+1]) 
     ans[key] = new_dict
```

o/p

```
{'Cabusao': {'Crop land mixed with coconut plantation': 12422544.53643799,
  'Coconut plantations': 1556695.0128784233,
  'Cultivated Area mixed with brushland/grassland': 4356221.33416748,
  'Arable land, crops mainly cereals and sugar': 11530447.4974976}
}
```

Comment: I think we can also use operator.add and itertools's reduce and groupby here and make it look more pythonic :)

Comment: I think this would work. I'm still trying to understand what your code does. Since I'm looping through an entire CSV, I get the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'` for line `new_dict[sub_list[idx]] += float(sub_list[idx+1])`. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Ahh that's weird; But make sure that d is `{'Cabusao': ['Crop land mixed with coconut plantation', '6446690.72729492', 'Coconut plantations', '156914.753356934', 'Cultivated Area mixed with brushland/grassland', '4356221.33416748', 'Arable land, crops mainly cereals and sugar', '11530447.4974976', 'Crop land mixed with coconut plantation', '5975853.80914307', 'Coconut plantations', '9898.44506835938', 'Coconut plantations', '1389881.81445313'],}`

Comment: The way it works is that even indices have the strings and the odd ones have the nos corresponding to them; hence if key is already in dict, simply increment the previous value

Comment: Cabusao is just one of the 39 municipalities of my CSV. I'm tracking down where the error happens. But your code is a huge help, definitely a challenge to understand and adapt to my code.

Comment: Play around your CSV; I am sure you will be able to crack the problem!